# Find and attach container dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

HTML:

```
a#myname
div#tooltip-myname

a#yourname
div#tooltip-yourname
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myname').tooltip($('#tooltip-myname'));
$('#yourname').tooltip($('#tooltip-yourname'));
```

How do I automate the tooltip container part so I don't have to manually enter '`#tooltip-myname`' '`#tooltip-yourname`' and so on with each tooltip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, like this:

```
$('#myname, #yourname').each(function() {
 $(this).tooltip($('#tooltip-' + this.id));
});
```

If those elements had a class, it gets easier to maintain, for example if they both had `class="hasTooltip"` you could use [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead, like this:

```
$('.hasTooltip').each(function() {
 $(this).tooltip($('#tooltip-' + this.id));
});
```

Then you could add as many as you wanted without editing the script.